# Replace Json string in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, string-substitution

First, I have a json:

```
 json = "{\"string_1\": \"{{string_1_value}}\", \"number_1\": \"{{number_1_value}}\"}"
```

And this hash:

```
hash = {
 "{{string_1_value}}" => "test" //string
 "{{number_1_value}}" => 2 //integer
}
```

What I'd like to do is to replace json with this hash and generate below json.

```
"{\"string_1\": \"test\", \"number_1\": 2}"
```

When I do this by `String#gsub`, I got an Error.

```
    hash.map {|k, v| json.gsub!(k, v)}
 => TypeError (no implicit conversion of Integer into String)
```

I don't want `2` to be string, i.e.)
"{"string_1": "test", "number_1": "2"}"

Do you have any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in ruby comments are marked by `#` not `//`. And remember about the comma in hash.

`gsub` is not the fastest way to replace things, it's better to convert json to regular hash and then convert it again to json.

```rb
require 'json'

json = "{\"string_1\": \"{{string_1_value}}\", \"number_1\": \"{{number_1_value}}\"}"
hash = {
 "{{string_1_value}}" => "test", #string
 "{{number_1_value}}" => 2 #integer
}

# First you should parse your json and change it to hash:
parsed_json = JSON.parse(json)
# Then create keys array
keys = parsed_json.keys
# Create new empty hash
new_hash = {}
# And now fill new hash with keys and values 
# (take a look at to_s, it converts values to a String)
hash.each.with_index do |(_k, v), i|
  new_hash[keys[i]] = v.to_s
end
# Convert to json at the end
new_hash.to_json
#  => "{\"string_1\":\"test\",\"number_1\":\"2\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Regexp`,`Hash` version of `String#gsub` to just substitute the patterns with the desired values as follows:

```
require 'json'
json_string = "{\"string_1\": \"{{string_1_value}}\", \"number_1\": \"{{number_1_value}}\"}"

original_hash= {
 "{{string_1_value}}" => "test", #string
 "{{number_1_value}}" => 2 #integer
}

#Convert JSON to hash and invert the key value pairs 
parsed_json = JSON.parse(json_string).invert
#=>{"{{string_1_value}}"=>"string_1", "{{number_1_value}}"=>"number_1"}

# Convert the hash to JSON and substitute the patterns 
original_hash.to_json.gsub(/\{\{.+?\}\}/, parsed_json) 
#=> "{\"string_1\":\"test\",\"number_1\":2}"
```